# Embedding client-side blazor in an angular or react app

Tags: .net, reactjs, angular, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Trying to embed a blazor component into an existing angular app and having buttons in the angular app call into the blazor component. As an example, I'd like to embed this asteroids game into my existing angular SPA and have a button in the SPA that starts the game.

https://github.com/aesalazar/AsteroidsWasm

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?